# How to make an invisible field visible again in odoo 15

Tags: python, xml, odoo, erp, odoo-15

In the sales module in odoo, when the client wants to create a new sales quotation, the Quotation date is not visible. So in developer mode, i went into the form view and realised it had an attribute attached to it with an invisible attribute. I tried deleting the whole attribute but that doesn't seem to work, i only see it in developer mode. How do i make this field visible for the client to input a quotation date so it reflects in the frontend?
Below is the code:

`<field name="date_order" nolabel="1" groups="base.group_no_one" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'in', ['sale', 'done', 'cancel'])]}"/>`

And this is the group it is added to:

````
<group name="order_details">
                            <field name="validity_date" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'in', ['sale', 'done'])]}"/>
                            <div class="o_td_label" groups="base.group_no_one" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'in', ['sale', 'done', 'cancel'])]}">
                                <label for="date_order" string="Quotation Date"/>
                            </div>
                            <field name="date_order" nolabel="1" groups="base.group_no_one" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'in', ['sale', 'done', 'cancel'])]}"/>
                            <div class="o_td_label" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'in', ['draft', 'sent'])]}">
                                <label for="date_order" string="Order Date"/>
                            </div>
                            <field name="date_order" attrs="{'required': [('state', 'in', ['sale', 'done'])], 'invisible': [('state', 'in', ['draft', 'sent'])]}" nolabel="1"/>
                            <field name="show_update_pricelist" invisible="1"/>
                            <label for="pricelist_id" groups="product.group_product_pricelist"/>
                            <div groups="product.group_product_pricelist" class="o_row">
                                <field name="pricelist_id" options="{'no_open':True,'no_create': True}"/>
                                <button name="update_prices" type="object" string=" Update Prices" help="Recompute all prices based on this pricelist" class="btn-link mb-1 px-0" icon="fa-refresh" confirm="This will update all unit prices based on the currently set pricelist." attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('show_update_pricelist', '=', False), ('state', 'in', ['sale', 'done','cancel'])]}"/>
                            </div>
                            <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                            <field name="tax_country_id" invisible="1"/>
                            <field name="payment_term_id" options="{'no_open':True,'no_create': True}"/>
                        </group>```

Is there a way i could make the quotation date visible or it's an access right thing?
````

Comment: Hvae you tried to remove groups="base.group_no_one" ?

Comment: I just did, that seemed to work. Thanks
Only that the selected date does not reflect in the frontend. It still picks the current date after saving

Answer (score 2):

The first [label and date field](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/sale/views/sale_views.xml#L326) are used to show the quotation date for users who belong to the `Technical Features` group and the second [label and date field](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/sale/views/sale_views.xml#L330) are used to show the order date for users who has access to the sale order.

It is supposed to have the creation date of the draft/sent quotations (does not need to be edited).

You can make the field visible for those users by removing the `group` attribute, adding a user to the `Technical features` group, or by adding a new group like following:

```
<div class="o_td_label" groups="base.group_no_one,{GROUP_EXTERNAL_ID}" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'in', ['sale', 'done', 'cancel'])]}">
    <label for="date_order" string="Quotation Date"/>
</div>
<field name="date_order" nolabel="1" groups="base.group_no_one,{GROUP_EXTERNAL_ID}" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'in', ['sale', 'done', 'cancel'])]}"/>
```

Comment: Yup, this works. thanks for the detailed explanation and other options to resolve this issue. The system still picks the current date even after selecting a different date

Comment: @Nate ask that in another question ;-)

Comment: @Nate
to change the order date use "sh_sale_backdate" model in odoo app store